# Como utilizar las funciones c++

Tags: dev-c++

Buenas me podrían ayudar a comprobar porque no puedo retornar la función o que esta mal en el código ya que soy nuevo en la programación y no se como aplicar las funciones

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

float areatri (float base, float altura);
int main()
{
float ba, al;
cout << "Ingrese la base del triangulo: ";
cin >> ba;
cout << "Ingrese la altura del triangulo: ";
cin >> al;
cout <<areatri(float area);
getch();
return 0;
}

float areatri (float base, float altura)
{
    float area;
    area= (ba*al)/2;
    return area;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu función `areatri` no existe ninguna variable `ba` o `al`. Tienes dos parámetros llamados `base` y `altura`.

Probablemente quieras decir:

```
float areatri (float base, float altura)
{
    float area;
    area = (base * altura)/2;
    return area;
}
```

Para llamar la función debes escribir su nombre y entre paréntesis indicar el literal o la variable cuyo valor recibirá cada parámetro.

Por ejemplo:

```
areatri(1, 2);
// El parámetro base será 1 y altura 2
```

O como intuyo que quieres hacerlo en tu código:

```
areatri(ba, al);
// El parámetro base será el valor de ba
// y altura será el valor de al
```

Comment: Gracias ya  esta solucionado y ya entendí lo que tengo que implementar